# USB Drive is Read-Only on Mac

Tags: hard-drive, mac, usb, usb-storage

I have a MacBook Pro(13.3.1 (22E261)) that has a USB Drive(Seagate Model SRD00F1). I have the NTFS Paragon Driver installed. This was working fine. Now it is read-only. I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling the Paragon Software driver. It still is just read-only. It seems to be mounted fine in Disk Utility and System Information. I can see all of the files on the drive. I can also see the files fine when I attach them to a Windows machine.

Comment: Check system prefs [settings] for full disk access - https://www.seagate.com/gb/en/support/kb/seagate-software-blocked-on-macos-007810en/

Comment: Checked the system prefs and there are no prompts.

Comment: Why did someone -1 this??

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas I wondered the same thing.

Comment: It's ok. I gave it back to you. :)

Answer (score 0):

The issue was resolved by following the advice from Paragon Software:

1. Uninstall the currently installed version as described here:  How To
   Uninstall Microsoft NTFS For Mac By Paragon Software If you were
   using NTFS for Mac 14, you can remove it in System Preferences -
   NTFS for Mac - Settings - Uninstall, or using NTFS for Mac 14 DMG.
2. Reboot your Mac
3. Download and install the installation package

Seagate: http://ftp.paragon.eu.com/support/att/OEM/NTFS-15.10.593.dmg       or
Western Digital: http://ftp.paragon.eu.com/support/att/OEM/NTFS-15.10.592.dmg

The new version of software fixed the issue.